# Objective C - sqlite3_open Memory leak even though sqlite3_close() applied

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite, memory-leaks

I am getting memory leaks at sqlite3_open even though sqlite_close, sqlite3_finalize are applied, please guide me where I am going wrong. Project is in Non - ARC.

```
     -(BOOL)saveMedia:(NSDictionary *)details Download:(NSInteger)completed
{
    //NSLog(@"media savemedia %@",[details objectForKey:@"type"]);
    BOOL saved = FALSE;
    NSInteger exists = [self findMedia:[details objectForKey:@"media_id"] playlist_id:[details objectForKey:@"playlist_id"] type:[details objectForKey:@"type"]];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;

    self.databasePath = [self getDBPath];
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &wazzupco) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *query_stmt;
        if (exists == 0)
        {
            query_stmt = "INSERT INTO media (media_id, title, description, file, views, thumbnail, version, playlist, playlist_id, author, created_at, type, playlist_created, timeout, playlist_order, media_order, playlist_promo_text, playlist_promo_url, playlist_promo_img,video_promo_text, video_promo_url, video_promo_img, dev_id, device_id, downloaded,slide_timeout) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        }
        else if([[details objectForKey:@"version"] integerValue] > exists)
        {
            NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE %@ SET media_id=?, title=?, description=?, file=?, views=?, thumbnail=?, version=?, playlist=?, playlist_id=?, author=?, created_at=?, type=?, playlist_created=?, timeout=?, playlist_order=?, media_order=?, playlist_promo_text=?, playlist_promo_url=?, playlist_promo_img=?,video_promo_text=?, video_promo_url=?, video_promo_img=?, dev_id=?, device_id=?, downloaded=?, slide_timeout=? WHERE media_id='%@' AND playlist_id='%@' AND type='%@'", TABLE_MEDIA, [details objectForKey:@"media_id"], [details objectForKey:@"playlist_id"], [details objectForKey:@"type"]];
            query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
        }
        else
        {
            //to make sure we won't update the database entry unless its a newer version
            return FALSE;
        }
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(wazzupco, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [[details objectForKey:@"media_id"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [[details objectForKey:@"title"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [[details objectForKey:@"description"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 4, [[details objectForKey:@"file"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 5, [[details objectForKey:@"views"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 6, [[details objectForKey:@"thumbnail"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 7, [[details objectForKey:@"version"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 8, [[details objectForKey:@"playlist"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 9, [[details objectForKey:@"playlist_id"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 10, [[details objectForKey:@"author"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 11, [[details objectForKey:@"created_at"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 12, [[details objectForKey:@"type"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 13, [[details objectForKey:@"playlist_created"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 14, [[details objectForKey:@"timeout"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 15, [[details objectForKey:@"playlist_order"] intValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 16, [[details objectForKey:@"media_order"] intValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 17, [[details objectForKey:@"playlist_promo_text"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 18, [[details objectForKey:@"playlist_promo_url"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 19, [[details objectForKey:@"playlist_promo_img"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 20, [[details objectForKey:@"video_promo_text"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 21, [[details objectForKey:@"video_promo_url"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 22, [[details objectForKey:@"video_promo_img"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 23, [[details objectForKey:@"dev_id"] intValue]);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 24, [[details objectForKey:@"device_id"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);
        sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 25, (int)completed);
        sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 26, [[details objectForKey:@"slide_timeout"] UTF8String], -1, NULL);        
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {
            NSLog(@"media added. type:%@",[details objectForKey:@"type"]);
            saved = TRUE;
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        //sqlite3_free(statement);
        //sqlite3_reset(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(wazzupco);
    if (completed != 0 && saved)
    {
        [self updateMediaStatus:[details objectForKey:@"file"] Download:1];
    }

    return saved;
}
```

In the above code I am inserting or updating data from a NSdictionary to sqlite table by considering if the data already exists or not. The method executes fine but it produce serious of memory leaks (the method is called multiple times from a loop), when checked in Instrument it is showing the leak is at if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &wazzupco) == SQLITE_OK).

From Instrument

Leaked Object: Malloc 64Bytes

## 18

Address 
Size: 1.12KB
Responsible Library: libsqlite3.dylib
Responsible Frame: 0x34bdce30

Comment: Why are you ignoring `sqlite3_prepare_v2()`'s return code?

Comment: @CL. Should I need to add a condition, if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(wazzupco, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)) and include the block of code inside the same. Can you please explain.

Comment: Yes; otherwise you won't notice errors (or just see your app blowing up later).

Comment: @CL. Thanks; I was not aware of that, I have updated my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the memory leak in the above code occurs when the "else" case is executed.

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &wazzupco) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    const char *query_stmt;
    if (exists == 0)
    {
        query_stmt = "INSERT INTO media (media_id, title, description, file, views, thumbnail, version, playlist, playlist_id, author, created_at, type, playlist_created, timeout, playlist_order, media_order, playlist_promo_text, playlist_promo_url, playlist_promo_img,video_promo_text, video_promo_url, video_promo_img, dev_id, device_id, downloaded,slide_timeout) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    }
    else if([[details objectForKey:@"version"] integerValue] > exists)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE %@ SET media_id=?, title=?, description=?, file=?, views=?, thumbnail=?, version=?, playlist=?, playlist_id=?, author=?, created_at=?, type=?, playlist_created=?, timeout=?, playlist_order=?, media_order=?, playlist_promo_text=?, playlist_promo_url=?, playlist_promo_img=?,video_promo_text=?, video_promo_url=?, video_promo_img=?, dev_id=?, device_id=?, downloaded=?, slide_timeout=? WHERE media_id='%@' AND playlist_id='%@' AND type='%@'", TABLE_MEDIA, [details objectForKey:@"media_id"], [details objectForKey:@"playlist_id"], [details objectForKey:@"type"]];
        query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
    }
    else
    {
        //to make sure we won't update the database entry unless its a newer version
        return FALSE;
    }
```

When the else case is fired, the sqlite3_close() is not reached and will leads to a memory leak at sqlite3_open

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Iam not familiar with these SQL Lite and non ARC projects After some googling i found this solution for You.I thing You should consider converting the project to ARC. ARC will handle the memory management for you. When ARC is turned on, the compiler will insert the appropriate memory management statements such as retain and release messages. It is best to use ARC as the compiler has a better idea of an object's life cycle and is less prone to human error

to convert the non ARC project to an ARC enabled one. This website might help you [Enable ARC](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/04/enabling-arc-cocos2d-project-howto-stepbystep-tutorialguide/)

Comment: Thanks Sarath, but I can't convert the project to ARC at this point as there are many libraries used, where the conversion will be difficult

Comment: Its ok :) . Hope some one will come with the right answer